# MySQL Match Against for exact Phrase working partially

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, mysql-5.7, exact-match

I have a table in which I created FullText index in a column called `item_desc`.

Let's say table contains three records in which column item_desc includes "Sodium Chloride" like following:

1. Solution Sodium Chloride standard
2. 5425 Sodium Chloride 100u
3. QtySodium Chloride solution

I have a following (Match, Against) query which supposed to be return rows by exact matching the records but it is returning only first two rows against **Sodium Chloride** and doesn't consider the phrase if it is concatenated with another word like QtySodium Chloride.

`SELECT * FROM tblhugedata WHERE MATCH(Item_desc) AGAINST('"*Sodium Chloride*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Following LIKE query returns expected results but I want to use only FullText index.

`SELECT * FROM tblhugedata WHERE Item_desc like '%SODIUM CHLORIDE%';`

Is there anyway to extract such results by match, Against way.

Comment: Remove the asterisks.  FULLTEXT does _not_ allow for _leading_ wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the asterisks.  FULLTEXT does *not* allow for *leading* wildcards.  That is, there is no way to get `MATCH` to match `QtySodium` against `Sodium`.

I would consider "QtySodium" to be "garbage in" and complain to the provider of the data.

Here is a kludge that will work in *some* cases:

```
WHERE WHERE MATCH(Item_desc) AGAINST('Sodium Chloride' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND Item_desc LIKE '%SODIUM CHLORIDE%'
```

That way, it will efficiently filter down to rows that have *either* "Sodium" or "Chloride", then check such rows for exactly the substring "Sodium Chloride".  That will match your 3 examples, but perhaps not some other examples.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked for me with little changes. e.g. it was searching `QtySodium` but not searching 123Sodium so when I put `*` in `Against` like following so it searching both: `WHERE MATCH(Item_desc) AGAINST('*Sodium Chloride*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND Item_desc LIKE '%SODIUM CHLORIDE%'`.But I still didn't understand how MySQL using Fulltext Index even with `LIKE` query!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tblhugedata WHERE MATCH(Item_desc) AGAINST(  'Sodium Chloride' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);

InnoDB full-text search does not support the use of multiple operators on a single search word.